# Ansible Command Line output

Tags: ansible

I am having an issue learning Ansible and getting feedback from it.

Here is the code I am running

```bash
clear && sudo ansible-playbook patching.yml -u stackoverflow -k --ask-become-pass -v
```

Here is my patching.yml file

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: Patching
    apt: update_cache=yes force_apt_get=yes

  - name: Proof of Patching
    shell: apt -q -y --ignore-hold --allow-change-held-packages --allow-unauthenticated -s dist-upgrade | /bin/grep  ^Inst | wc -l
    register: output

  - debug: var=output
```

What I am trying to accomplish is one to learn Ansible and two to patch my various Linux machines with some sort of feedback that they have patched I am getting this feedback after reading stack overflow for some time. It is long and un-human-friendly I would like it to be just a # or even better hostname: #.

Thank You

-Jared

Comment: Is there any reason or explanation why the second task "_Proof of Patching_" is NOT using the `apt` module like the first task "_Patching_"? According the [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#examples) there are several options possible. In other words, can you describe in more detail what you try to achieve?